# Does OneLogin support client session management via OIDC?

Tags: javascript, angular, openid, onelogin, openid-connect

I've setup an OIDC Connect App inside my OneLogin account and was already able to login different users using this client

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

and the "implicit flow".

The oidc-client-js supports session management out of the box using the iFrame mechanic to poll the IDP (onelogin in my case) about the status of the users session.

https://brockallen.com/2016/08/12/check-session-support-in-oidc-client-js/

The OIDC client does not even start doing so since in my signin return data there is no "session_state" value, instead it is just undefined.

I was reading the OIDC specs about it

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

and from paragraph 2-5 there are all the things the IDP needs to offer in order to make session management work via OIDC.

Since I could not find anything in the OneLogin Docs, I would appreciate any hint, help, experiences with this specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html:

> 2.1.  OpenID Provider Discovery Metadata
>
> These OpenID Provider Metadata parameters MUST be included in the
>   Server's discovery responses when Session Management and Discovery are
>   supported:
>
> check_session_iframe ...
>
> end_session_endpoint ...

I don't see these metadata parameters in the [OneLogin discovery metadata](https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration), so it looks like Session Management is not supported.

Comment: That matches my research. I thought there might be another source to get some more informations about it maybe even a onelogin dev to check this out. Anyway thanks for the answer, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm the product manager for OpenId Connect at OneLogin. The accepted answer is correct. We don't currently support the session management spec but are considering it as a future roadmap item.

Comment: Is there any update on whether this will be considered as a roadmap item? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not yet. You can suggest and vote for roadmap features on our ideas portal. https://onelogin.ideas.aha.io/

Comment: I would like to see this implemented!